# How can I return the percentage frequency of the best lag chosen in VAR(2) Simulation chosen by Akaike Criteria

Tags: matlab, time-series, linear-regression, model-comparison

If I put a counter loop before simulating a 3-dimensional VAR(2) model and after computing lets say AIC and lag 3 is chosen as the best fitted lag then I had difficulty in calculating the percentage frequency of the  best lag (or in other words how many times this best lag is chosen in the 100 simulations)?

Comment: please post your code, your expected results and some data. add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, save the lag of the current simulation in a vector. For example:

```
sims_count = 100;
lags = NaN(sims_count,1);

for i = 1:sims_count
    % your simulation here...
    lags(i) = simulation_lag;
end
```

Then, once the iteration is over and your `lags` vector has been filled, in order to calculate the frequency of the lags that match the best lag (equal to `3`), just use the following code:

```
best_lag_freq = sum(lags == 3) / sims_count;
```

A practical, stand-alone, example:

```
lags = randi(3,100,1);
best_lag_freq = sum(lags == 3) / 100;
```